# WSO2 login screen timeouts?

Tags: authentication, wso2, timeout

Back when we were running the regular Apereo CAS, there was a setting for login session timeouts, so that if someone went to the CAS login screen and just let it sit, the login session would timeout after a certain period of time (5-10 minutes IIRC.)

I was curious if there was a similar configuration settings with WSO2, and if so, what parameter it is?

The reason I'm asking is because on Saturday we did our first round of incoming student registrations, and apparently the Admissions folks logged in all of the lab computers and got them to the login screen about an hour before the students went to use them, and no one could log in until they refreshed their browsers. So I'm expecting that there is a setting for that somehow, I'm just not sure which setting it would be. Just looking at the identity.xml file, there are quite a few configurable timeout settings, and I'm not sure if it's even one of these:

```
...../repository/conf/identity # cat identity.xml | grep -i timeout
<CleanUpTimeout>720</CleanUpTimeout>
<CleanUpTimeout>2</CleanUpTimeout>
<SessionIdleTimeout>720</SessionIdleTimeout>
<RememberMeTimeout>10080</RememberMeTimeout>
<AppInfoCacheTimeout>-1</AppInfoCacheTimeout>
<AuthorizationGrantCacheTimeout>-1</AuthorizationGrantCacheTimeout>
<SessionDataCacheTimeout>-1</SessionDataCacheTimeout>
<ClaimCacheTimeout>-1</ClaimCacheTimeout>
<PersistanceCacheTimeout>157680000</PersistanceCacheTimeout>
<SessionIndexCacheTimeout>157680000</SessionIndexCacheTimeout>
<ClientTimeout>10000</ClientTimeout>
<!--<Cache name="AppAuthFrameworkSessionContextCache" enable="false" timeout="1" capacity="5000"/>-->
<CacheTimeout>120</CacheTimeout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global configuration can be found in the < IS_HOME >/repository/conf/identity/identity.xml file under the < TimeConfig >element.

```
<TimeConfig>
     <SessionIdleTimeout>15</SessionIdleTimeout>
     <RememberMeTimeout>20160</RememberMeTimeout>
</TimeConfig>
```

More information can be found [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+Session+Timeout).

mgt console session timeout: Open repository/conf/tomcat/carbon/WEB-INF/web.xml Increase the session-timeout value.

```
<session-config>
        <session-timeout>240</session-timeout>
        <cookie-config>
            <secure>true</secure>
        </cookie-config>
    </session-config>
```

Comment: (Is there a way to tag code as code in comments?)

Hmm, mine's currently set to

    <TimeConfig>
    <SessionIdleTimeout>720</SessionIdleTimeout>
    <RememberMeTimeout>10080</RememberMeTimeout>
    </TimeConfig>

but the login screen times out after 15 minutes. Is there another place I should be looking?

Comment: mgt console session timeout:
Open repository/conf/tomcat/carbon/WEB-INF/web.xml
Increase the session-timeout value.

Comment: Cool, thank you. Our next outage window is June 22nd, so I'll test out that change then :)